# Pass Output Variables to the Run Result

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

According to the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#variable) output variables should be contained in the response of the GET /runs method.

My pipeline looks like:

```
steps:
- bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]my value"
  name: setOutputValue
```

So I would expect to have the variable "myOutputVar" within the response. In my case the "variables" section is completely missing.

Is there another way of passing output variables, so they become available via REST API?

Comment: I don't see in the docs that output variables should be contained in the response, only regular variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline

Comment: Even if variables are set explicitly at the beginning of the pipeline YAML file, the "variables" field in the response is empty. So what to set to the "variables" populated.